# How can I reduce build time using a parallel build / parallelizing the tests?

Tags: java, build-process, junit, teamcity, parallel-processing

Simple question :)

How can I reduce build time using a parallel build / parallelizing the tests?

We're using TeamCity, JUnit, Fit, Selenium

Comment: The real answer depends on what continuous integration, build, and test automation tools you are using.

Comment: TeamCity, JUnit, Fit, Selenium

Comment: how long do your tests take to run..?

Comment: full build is like 30 minutes I think.  We don't run it all before committing, just the fast tests.

Comment: How can you know your question is simple when you yourself can not answer it?

Comment: Since when does a simple question imply knowing the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **distcc** for C/C++  to distribute the build across several computers.

Use **ccache** to cache compiler work that's been done before. Good luck.

Comment: A real-life build process rarely consists of running the C/C++ compiler only. But these two tools are good starting point for certain scenarios.